# Putting a URI into a FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, uri, fileinputstream

For an assignment, we are required to be able to save a custom file type and then be able to read it back in again. I figured I could use the FileInputStream class so that I could easily just use myInStream.read() to get all of the information I need from the file. However, I've run into a problem with getting the file into the FileInputStream. I was able to get the URI, but it seems the method I used to get the URI makes a URI type that is incompatible with the File class. I have the following code in my onActivityResult() right before I start reading:

```
    Uri pickedFile = data.getData();
    File myFile = new File(pickedFile);
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

On the second line it says "Cannot resolve constructor 'File(android.net.Uri)'", so I'm assuming I must have to convert the URI to a different format, but I have no idea how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
For future reference the fixed code looks like this:
        Uri pickedFile = data.getData();
        InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedFile);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm assuming I must have to convert the URI to a different format

No. A `Uri` is an opaque handle to some content, such as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893406/putting-a-uri-into-a-fileinputstream`. It is not a file.

You do not show where your `Uri` is coming from. My guess, given the named `pickedFile`, is that you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. In neither case is the user picking a file.

If my guess is correct as to where the `Uri` is coming from, that `Uri` will have either a `file` scheme or a `content` scheme. You can get an `InputStream` on either type of `Uri` the same way: call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. You get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I don't know why I thought I needed FileInputStreams instead of InputStreams. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 13):

I do it like this:

```
FileInputStream importdb = new FileInputStream(_context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r").getFileDescriptor());
```